# Displaying portuguese characters Android

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app and when it was suposed to write words like "não" or "cabeça", with characters with "~" or "ç" for example, it writes "Ã£" or "Ã§". I already checked source files encoding and it is UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like UTF8 interpreted as ISO-8859-x.

In theory, you could supply the javac compiler `-encoding UTF-8` on the command line but that would be the wrong solution.

Instead, move all your user-facing strings to an XML resource file. In there unicode character encoding works out of the box.

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html