# Special characters on android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm developing an android app on eclipse on my mac. I run it and the special characters like á é í ó ú ñ work well. Now I have to develop on my linux machine(using eclipse too) and when i run it, the special characters don't work. For instance, instead of the word in spanish qué it appears quÃ©. I don't know what is happening, if it is because of the JDK or anything...
Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: What's the encoding of your code files?

Comment: make your files utf8 using notepad

Comment: do you have tried with charecter encoding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560769/displaying-portuguese-characters-android/18560910#18560910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you accessing the same files on different machine and Eclipse shows characters wrong?

Please look:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding
```

on your Eclipse and check if there is a difference between machines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse was my source.

Comment: Also, check your project properties in Resource section as well as individual files. They should be all UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are using the wrong characters, or the characters are not suported.